# Trying to create a NAS on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab, nfs, nas

I am new to linux and am trying to make a NAS out of an old comnputer, I was going to use FreeNAS but my computer didnt reach the requirements. Here are the specs of my computer if anyone has suggestions

```
Intel Pentium 4 
512 MiB RAM
40GB HHD+ 150GB HHD
```

Annyways, so I followed a tutorial on how to turn a Raspberry Pi into a NAS (because it seemed like it could work) link: http://www.tinkernut.com/portfolio/make-raspberry-pi-nas-network-attached-storage/ but when i ran

```
sudo mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /media/NASDrive
```

it said this

mount: worng fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

```
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg  tail or so.
```

so then after seeing that I typed in google the exact thing and did 
    sudo apt-get install nfs-common

and tried again but this is what it says the same thing as before. I also tried

```
mount.nfs /dev/sda1 /media/NASDrive
```

and it gave this response

```
mount.nfs: failed to apply fstab options
```

Now I don't know what to do and thought Id firsts ask and then continue.

Comment: Much more information is needed for a good answer.  Did you already install Ubuntu on your old computer?  What version?  Did you share the drives on this old computer using samba? If not, how did you share them?  Basically we need to know how you set up the NAS to help you connect to it.